# An assumption used in defining a group of order $mn$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to show that the defining relations $a^m=b^n=e, ab=ba^k$ define a group of order $mn$ with a normal subgroup of order $m$, if $k^n \equiv 1 \pmod m$.

Consider the set of symbols of the form $b^q a^r$, where $q \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}, r \in \{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}$.  This set forms a group: Closure holds because $(b^q a^r)(b^s a^t) = b^{q+s} a^{rk^s +t }$.  It follows that the inverse of $b^q a^r$ is $b^s a^t$ where $s=-q=n-q$ and $t=-rk^s=m-rk^{n-q}$. Associativity can also be verified.  Finally, let $A:=\{a^r: r=0,1,\ldots,m-1\}$.  Then $A$ is a normal subgroup since $(b^q a^r)^{-1} a^s (b^q a^r) = a^{-r} b^{-q} a^s b^q a^r = a^{-r} b^{-q+q} a^{sk^q +r} = a^{sk^q} \in A$.

My question is on why the assumption $k^n \equiv 1 \pmod m$ is necessary?  (It is mentioned in this exercise, but I don't see where I used it in the proof.)

Comment: Have you checked that all of the elements you wrote down are distinct? Maybe it is needed there.

Comment: You would need to use that condition when verifying associativity.

Comment: For associativity, we have $(b^q a^r b^s a^t)b^x a^y = b^{q+s+x} a^{(rk^s+t)k^x+y}$, and $b^q a^r (b^s a^t b^x a^y) = b^{q+s+x} a^{rk^{s+x} + tk^x +y}$, both products are equal.  But where is the condition used?

Answer (score 2):

Prove by induction on $t$ that $b^{-1}ab = a^k \Rightarrow b^{-t}ab^t = a^{k^t}$ for all $t \ge 0$, then putting $t=n$ gives $a = a^{k^n}$, so $k^n \equiv 1 \bmod m$.

Comment: hmmm... something is not clear to me. It looks like: in order to ensure the structure is a group (or that the defining relations are well defined), the condition $k^n \equiv 1 \pmod m$ is necessary (and it may be possible that other conditions can also be derived), but that this condition isn't used anywhere to prove that the given structure is a group.  Am I correct?  When providing some defining relations, does one take any systematic approach to obtain all necessary conditions on the parameters and mention those conditions as well?  I would think such conditions are redundant to mention.